# Cycle analog in julialang

Tags: julia

I'm pretty much fortran person. I'm losing my mind with a julia analog of cycle in fortran.
By the way, goto statements doesn't work at this naive try:

```
x == y ? continue : goto mark1

mark1: 
println("hello")
```

It raises:

```
syntax: extra token "mark1" after end of expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a function, `@goto` has now been implemented.

```
function example(y)
    for x in 1:1000
        x == y ? continue : @goto mark1
    end

    @label mark1
    println("hello")
end
```

See below for more information:

---

---

Although not traditionally considered loops, the `@goto` and `@label` macros can be used for more advanced control flow. One use case is when the failure of one part should lead to the retry of an entire function, often useful in input validation:

```
function getsequence()
    local a, b

@label start
    print("Input an integer: ")
    try
        a = parse(Int, readline())
    catch
        println("Sorry, that's not an integer.")
        @goto start
    end

    print("Input a decimal: ")
    try
        b = parse(Float64, readline())
    catch
        println("Sorry, that doesn't look numeric.")
        @goto start
    end

    a, b
end
```

However, this use case is often more clear using recursion:

```
function getsequence()
    local a, b

    print("Input an integer: ")
    try
        a = parse(Int, readline())
    catch
        println("Sorry, that's not an integer.")
        return getsequence()
    end

    print("Input a decimal: ")
    try
        b = parse(Float64, readline())
    catch
        println("Sorry, that doesn't look numeric.")
        return getsequence()
    end

    a, b
end
```

Although both examples do the same thing, the second is easier to understand. However, the first one is more performant (because it avoids the recursive call). In most cases, the cost of the call does not matter; but in limited situations, the first form is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is a well-formed question, but there is an issue open for implementing local goto: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/101. There's even a pull request with a prototype implementation, but it's gotten a little bit stalled.

Comment: I mean, basically I would like to reproduce something like:
`Do i=1,50  ...[compute some stuff] ... if(condition.eq.true) cycle
Else ... End If End Do`. This is how I would implement it in Fortran, but what about julia? I have seen also https://github.com/dcjones/julia/commit/eba5c9fa321048ad344cc2c2194135c4a40211ea but looks pretty cryptic to me

Comment: I don't really understand what `cycle` does in Fortran despite some googling, so it's hard to give you a good answer. However, Julia has C-style `break` and `continue` keywords for loops, which may help you do what you want to: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/control-flow/#man-loops.

Comment: in case it helps, `cycle` in fortran = `continue` in C and `exit` in fortran = `break` in C

Comment: Ah, yes. I would guess that pretty much answers the question, but I'll leave it to the OP to decide that.

Comment: I found a work around about this issue that does exactly what I want, so I put it here if it can help to someone else: `flag = x>y; flag && continue `. This, inside a for loop, returns the control to it instead of executing a bunch of optional code.

Comment: Wouldn't that be equivalent to `x > y && continue`?

Comment: Shouldn't we avoid goto at all costs?  It is not as useful as its proponents espouse and its abuse makes code horrible to maintain.